# possible to make tunneling using linux webhosting with cpanel

Tags: linux, proxy, cpanel, tunnel

I'm having a Linux Webhosting account with  cpanel & whm..

i also see something ssh on cpanel.. i have heard about tunneling to make proxy.

my friend is having VPS server and is able to make tunneling using ssh via 443port.

i need to know if there is some possibility to make proxy browsing using my webhosting account..

i googled it and of not much help to me.. if possible also pl do link me with the the tutorial to make so...

Comment: Do you have to set up a proxy using an SSH tunnel?  What is the proxy for?  If you're just looking to set up a HTTP proxy server, you don't need to tunnel through SSH.  Instead, you can use something like PHProxy or Glype, which would be easier to set up with a WHM/CP host.